# element tabbing with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dhtml

Im struggling to create a tabbing technique using jquery so that the user can use the tab key and navigate through the anchor tags within a container div.  I would like the active anchor to become highlighted whilst tabbing through.  Is this possible?
Thanks,

My attempt below, this fails.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabindex = 1;
    var obj = $('#myDiv').find('a').first().focus();
    $('#myDiv').find('a').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("tabindex", tabindex);
        $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px black');
        tabindex++;
    });
});
```

Comment: "fails" isn't enough detail. Try to describe precisely what happens after you run this script.

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/HNgNn/

Comment: from this example on jsfiddle im not sure how to add a background-color highlight style when the user is using the 'tab' key and navigating through the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabbing essentially focuses a control. You can simply subscribe to the [focus](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffocus%2F&ei=SjmSUJyOAeri4QSDiIGIAw&usg=AFQjCNGfEWD0Gh8BgmLZoJPkc-U6HFjLLA&sig2=9r_p5FhH1C-N67MYrqcCbQ) event.

So assuming you have a `highlight` function somewhere, and a `selector` string for items in tab order:

```
$(selector).focus(function() { highlight($(this)); } );
```